# Date value format is different when I use the same formula to calculate date in Stored Procedure - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to retrieve a value and from a select statement and later use that value in passing as a filter using binds . I get a date value "2021-07-05" when I just execute the SELECT statement in snowflake if I execute the same SELECT inside a Stored Procedure I get the value in Different Format as "Mon Jul 05 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)". I tried using TO_DATE, extract DATE_PART but nothing is working. Any ways to handle this and convert that value to "2021-07-05".

Code(s) used:

```
select TO_DATE(DATEADD(D,-1,CURRENT_DATE())) AS DATE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP()       
RETURNS VARCHAR LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$
var condition=`select TO_DATE(DATEADD(D,-1,CURRENT_DATE())) AS DT`;
var condition_check = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: condition}).execute();
condition_check.next();
var filter_condition = condition_check.getColumnValue(1);

        return filter_condition  
        $$;  

CALL TEST_SP();
```

I have attached the screenshots from snowflake after executing the above statements for your reference.[image: just select query][image: date format changed in SP]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stored procedure above is written in JavaScript and returns a VARCHAR -- a string.

As seen in the question:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP()       
RETURNS VARCHAR LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$
```

So as JavaScript is trying to return a Date value it gets transformed to String before landing in the Snowflake space -- and that's why you see a difference.

Try instead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP()       
RETURNS DATE LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$
```